# Proper way to present field name-value tuples in HTML?

Tags: html, tuples, presentation

I have a big form in a page and at some portions of it I have some static data that is not editable:

```
First name: John
Birthday: 1980/1/1
```

These fields are not part of the form (no input), etc. but rather hard-fixed values. I did try a few things but I am confused as to what is the most appropriate thing for this. I couldn't manage to find much information on this either.

My first take:

```
<div>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <span id="name">John</span>
  <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
  <span id="birthday">1980/1/1</span>
</div>
```

My second take:

```
<div>
  <span class="field-name">Name</span>
  <span class="field-value">John</span>
  <span class="field-name">Birthday</span>
  <span class="field-value">1980/1/1</span>
</div>
```

These are my two takes on this. I am baffled however if using `label` for static data in a non-form is even allowed? What's the best best table-less approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. Table element is actually **not** a bad way to represent a table.
2. You can use read-only input fields to indicate that the data belongs to a form but is not editable. For that, just add a `readonly="readonly"` attribute for an `input` element. (Just `readonly` will also do for non-XHTML documents.)
3. Labels `for` spans make very little sense since there is no interactivity in your `span`s. What are you trying to achieve?
4. If what is needed is just styling and you don't want to use a table for some reason, `span`s or `div`s with CSS styling through classes will probably work fine.